# Usage of -c in perl with code that modifies @INC

Tags: perl

Consider the following script "test.pl".

#### test.pl

```
#usr/bin/perl -w

push (@INC,"path_for_abc");
use abc;

#rest of the code ...
```

#### Command prompt:

```
$ perl -c test.pl
```

I know that I will have to add "use lib" pragma or have to push the path inside @INC in Begin block to make it work.

If the path for the module is not defined in defined in @INC,
Will "perl -c test.pl"  push the "path_for_abc" while snytax checking?

Comment: It will not, unless, as you mentioned, you `use lib`
or wrap the push into a `BEGIN` block.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What makes you think that `perl -c` is different from `perl` in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

No, your sample code won't find the "abc" module when run as `perl -c`. It won't find it when run *without* `-c` either but you appear to know that already. `use` happens at compile time. The `push` won't happen until runtime unless it's wrapped in a `BEGIN` block. If you do that (or `use lib`) then it *will* work under `perl -c`. From perlrun:

> **`-c`**
>
> causes Perl to check the syntax of the program and then exit
>   without executing it. Actually, it will execute and `BEGIN`, `UNITCHECK`,
>   or `CHECK` blocks and any `use` statements: these are considered as
>   occurring outside the execution of your program. `INIT` and `END` blocks,
>   however, will be skipped.